# Align radioButton drawable top left

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to create a radio button like this :

[image]

I'm using android:drawableTop in my XML layout, but in this way the drawable isn't horizontally aligned to the left, it is centered.

```
 <RadioGroup 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="RADIO 1"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
                <RadioButton 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RADIO 2"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you please show your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer i will tell you. But i think that is helpful. Take two images with texts also.

Write one selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_radiobutton" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_radiobutton" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Add those two radio buttons into drawable file. Then in the radiobutton can simply add button tag.

```
                          <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/lastvalue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:button="@drawable/autochoose_radio"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/lastvalue"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

In place of text you don't write any thing. I think this is the perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you Nava. Do you mean that I have to include the text inside the drawable? So it will be fixed? 
But how can I handle internationalization in this way? Usually I would put the radioButton text into file like strings.xml.

Comment: Yes.. In the Radiobutton bottom text is not possible i think. If you want you have to follow this procedure.